# Formal phrase for "in hopes that"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I'm using in hopes that in the following sentence. However, it does not seems to be formal and appropriate for a scientific paper. Is there any similar phrase that has the same meaning but more formal ? Thanks.

> To overcome this crucial issue, a popular solution has been used where
>   a task is assigned to many workers and the results for this task are
>   aggregated *in hopes that* the aggregated result is actually the correct
>   one.

Comment: How about 'under the auspices of'?

Comment: Might one ask why you are looking for a more formal equivalent?  Will you be addressing the Pope or the Queen of England, for instance?

Comment: I don't see anything "more formal" about *expecting*, *anticipating*, *expecting that*, *in expectation that*, *with expectation that* (or similar expressions using *belief*), compared with *in hopes that*. The verb *to hope* is not particularly informal, and none of the proposals are particularly formal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try **[expecting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hope)** or **[anticipating](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anticipating)**?

But in seriousness, *in hopes that* doesn't strike me as very colloquial, though it would seem in the context presented in this question that [want of something to happen](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hope) might be considered more non-scientific than something that has reason or justification to be correct.

In context:

> To overcome this crucial issue, a popular solution has been used where a task is assigned to many workers and the results for this task are aggregated **expecting that** the aggregated result is actually the correct one.

(I thought "that" was allowed to be optional, but since "the aggregated result is actually the correct one." is a complete sentence, "that" is a conjunction and necessary.)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of *in hopes that*, you could use phrases including *expectation* or *belief*, as in ***expecting that***, ***in expectation that***, ***with expectation that***, or similarly with *belief*.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem isn't formality, it's confidence.  "In the hopes that" implies you want something, but aren't sure at all that you'll get it; since this is a scientific paper, you probably want to sound a bit more confident than that!  "In the expectation that" works well.